# Custom checkbox field in wordpress does not get registered

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress theme with X-amount of form fields, but I need addition fields not given by the theme. So I tried adding my own, how ever the field always get's inserted as "NULL" in the database.

The form field is a simple checkbox, the HTML code looks like this

```
   <div class="form-group" syle="margin-left:5%;">
            <p><br><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="expert" name="ai" value="E" >
                <label for="expert">Expert</label>
            </p>
        </div>
```

and I've added the following PHP to see if it is selected

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {


    if (isset($_POST["ai"])) {
        if($_POST["ai"] == "E"){
            $_POST["ai"] == "E";
        }
        else{
            $_POST["ai"] == "N";
        }


    }

    ?>
```

I've tried replication what the theme does to add fields to the database, a field called "petition_user_ai" is being succefully added, but always contains NULL, it's being added via the this php

```
//line1010
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'petition_user_ai',  $user[ 'ai' ], true );

//line399
        $ai     = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'petition_user_ai', true );
```

See the entire php-file at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4pBAda45)

Comment: I don't know anything about wp but `=` is assignment not `==`.  Also, where does `$user[ 'ai' ]` in `update_user_meta` come from?  Maybe `$_POST["ai"]`?

Comment: I've changed to =, thank you. 

$user is ued to add the petitioner as a WordPress user with the role of petitioner. there is a $user_data array that I belive inserts data into the DB https://pastebin.com/2FedAMzR (this is also in the same file as I linked)

then "        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'petition_user_ai',  $user[ 'ai' ], true );" is run

Comment: what is the output of $user[ 'ai' ] , i think here comes the $_POST["ai"] value......like:---   update_user_meta( $user_id, 'petition_user_ai',  $_POST["ai"], true );

Comment: My echo's don't seem to work, I think this is because when I press submit a new page that shows "Thank you for signing this petition" shows up

Answer (score 0):

Remove `==` in assignment of value.  Assuming that here before if condition you are getting the value in the `$_post` .

```
if (isset($_POST["ai"])) {
    if($_POST["ai"] == "E"){
        $_POST["ai"] = "E";
    }
    else{
        $_POST["ai"] = "N";
    }
}
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 update_user_meta( $user->id , 'petition_user_ai',  $_POST[ 'ai' ], true );
```

Comment: Thank you, I implemented the changes, but the checkbox still returns NULL every time

Comment: Can you share your complete code with function and everything

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Pa7FcUkp <- class.petitions.php, residing in <theme>/extend/classes

https://pastebin.com/0B27v5Ai <- array.options.php, my additions are at the bottom. but these seem to be for a checkbox in the theme. I'm just adding the form field manually


Do you want *all* the code?

Comment: can you try it now

Comment: I just tested again now, the same problem persists.